# Nim: how can I make it closer to Python syntax?

Tags: python, nim-lang

I know it's generally NOT a good idea but I want to make Nim more "Pythonic". Examples:

1) instead of `proc`, use def

2) instead of `echo`, use `print`

3) instead of `readLine`, use `input`

4) instead of `parseJson` use `json.loads`

and so on.

Yes, it may not be possible to change the *behavior* of the functions and statements, but I'd like it to - at least - *look* like the "good old" Python ones.

Honestly, please don't explain me why you think it's a bad idea. I want to *play* and try it. No animals would be harmed, blah-blah.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think you can change a languages [keywords](http://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#lexical-analysis-identifiers-keywords)?

Comment: @CoryKramer knowing Nim only for 2 hours, I have no idea whether I can or can not do that. That's why I created this question.

Comment: @tobias_k yes actually this is what I though first, but maybe there is another more convenient way...

Comment: I don't know nim, but besides `def`, all the others are plain functions, so you'll want to define the Python-named functions and just mane them forward their arguments to the Nim builtins, adjusting the semantic if necessary.

Comment: Not a bad question. Maybe not a good idea to most people but seems like a valid question anyway.

Comment: Shameless plug -- https://yakshalang.github.io/ this is probably what you want. (I am the author)

Answer (score 3):

For `echo`, `readLine`, and `parseJson` you can look up their definitions in system.nim and json.nim and define your own procs. This should work:

```
import json

proc print*(x: varargs[expr, `$`]) {.magic: "Echo", tags: [WriteIOEffect], sideEffect.}

proc input*(f: File): TaintedString  {.tags: [ReadIOEffect], benign.}

proc loads(p: var JsonParser): JsonNode = parseJson(p)
```

Regarding `def`, I don't think it is possible with exactly the same syntax as for `proc`. If you want to, you can come up with some `def` macro, which itself generates the AST of some proc. But as far as I can see, the resulting syntax for defining a proc would be pretty ugly.